# Удаление последней строки

Tags: c#

Не могу нормально сформулировать вопрос)) суть в следующем, есть меню выбора, которое реагирует на enter и escape

```
var cki = Console.ReadKey();

            if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                Model.Logica();
            }
            if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                Environment.Exit(0);
```

Если печатать рандомные символы, то они потом остаются на консоли. Я нашел выход и перед консрукцией меню написал `Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;`
Есть менее корявый способ убрать ненужныю писанину?

Comment: `Console.Clear()` не пробовали? ...... https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.console.clear(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Console.Clear() очистит все, а мне надо, чтобы текстовая инструкция висела во время выполнения программы

Comment: Мммм. ну может эту саму инструкцию убрать в функцию типа `ShowInstructions()` и просто банально вызывать `clear()` и `ShowInstructions()` тем самым все очистив но создав иллюзию что  инструкция осталась....или я опять не так понял?))))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я понял о чем вы)) просто думал есть какой-то более элегантный способ. в любом случае спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А если так:

```
Console.ReadKey(intercept: true);
```

?

Comment: вооот) это оно) спасибо.

Comment: @cruim: Пожалуйста!